# How to get rid of the White fly

Tags: diseases

I noticed I got once again the white flies on my herbs and vegetables. I tried to get rid of it by planting Basil close to them, and it worked for some time but now they are back again.

I have heard and tried vinegar mixed with water? This time the flies are only under the leaves not on top of the leaves as before.

Comment: Is this an outdoor or indoor situation? What is nearby?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that companion planting works for pests.  It may work for other reasons.

An excerpt from [What Bugs Does Basil Attract?](https://livingboosts.com/does-basil-attract-bugs/)

> Bugs That Damage Basil
> Basil is attractive to many insect pests. Here are the most common.
>
> - Thrips
> - Aphids
> - Japanese beetles
> - Whiteflies
> - Flea beetles
> - Leaf miners
> - Cutworms
> - Loopers
> - Spider mites

So, Basil itself falls victim to white flies.

I would use some sort of oil such as

- Mineral Oil
- Neem Oil
- Conquer Oil (Yates)

We have used all three with success.

Answer (score 1):

I have always use on tablespoon of Dawn detergent with a gallon of water.  Spray on to the point of dripping, then rinse well.  Repeat every week.  I use this on my tomatoes and peppers for years.